# SQl query - 2 highest values for each group and second must be "younger" then first

Tags: mysql, sql

I have MySQL table. I need select two highest values for each group,
but second highest value can`t be "more recent". If the highest value for Project 1 is date '2015-12-01', the second highest value must be earlierl then '2015-12-01'. This date is user input within application, eg.: user input date '2014-01-03' and get 2 highest value order by date.

1. '2013-12-05' - 500 visits
2. '2013-10-11' -  480 viists

   ```
   + --------- + ----------- + ---------+
   | project   | visits      | date     |
   + --------- + ----------- + ---------+
   | 1         | 750         |2015-12-01|
   | 1         | 582         |2014-11-01|        
   | 1         | 423         |2013-10-02|
   | 2         | 666         |2016-01-01|
   | 2         | 812         |2012-02-02|
   | 2         | 450         |2014-03-05|
   + --------- + ----------- + -------- +
   ```

Edit: I try this (it is more complex then example above) + join table due to ProjectName

```
set @num := 0, @group := '';

select ProjectName,visits, date
                    from 
                    (
                    select date, Projects_ID, visits,
                    @num := if(@group = `Projects_ID`, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
                    @group := Projects_ID as col
                    from Hits
                    where date < '2016-01-11' and visits > 0
                    order by Projects_ID,date, visits desc
                    ) as x inner join Projects as p on x.Projects_ID = 
                    p.ID
                    where x.row_number <= 2
                    group by ProjectName,Projects_ID, date
```

I got table where was the highest value, but in some cases second highest value was "most recent" then highest value.

Comment: I don't understand the rules.  "dates" are not "younger" than other dates -- either earlier or later.  And, for your sample data, what is the expected results?

Comment: Your "user input date" statement doesn't make sense - how does the user-selected date relate to the query?

Comment: @KristenWaite user select input value through UI in my app..

Comment: @AntonínKučera right, but it is ambiguous from the statement whether the query looks at dates "younger" or "older" (and/or equal to, etc.) than your user-selected date. Also, you will get more help if you simplify and clean up your questions - your 1. + 2. "examples" do not line up with your table data example.

Comment: @KristenWaite yes, it is true, but the table example is not so important. I'm looking for solution my issue. It's general question. How can i get two highest value from table with condition: Second highest value can't be "more recent" then first highest value. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.visits, a.project, a.date 
FROM temper1 AS a 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) 
       FROM temper1 AS b 
       WHERE b.project = a.project AND b.date >= a.date
       ) <= 2 
ORDER BY a.visits ASC, a.date DESC
```

Comment: it does not work probably, query still runnig (a lot of minutes) .. Does exists faster solution?